# EF CORE 5 + MySql 5.7 group then select top 1 LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using **EF Core 5** to rewrite some sql statements from an older system, My DataBase is **MySql 5.7**, here is a quite simple SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CreateTime) AS LatestRecordTime,MemberId,TotalAmount,CostAmount,BonusAmount
FROM 
    CashFlowRecord
WHERE 
    CreateTime <= '2023-12-31'
    And TotalAmount>0
GROUP BY 
    MemberId;
```

A `CashFlowRecord` table stores all the users' flow records, I just need to fetch the latest cash flow record for each member/ user, so using `MAX(CreateTime)` works well for me.

**Problem**: how to properly rewrite this sql query to EF core LINQ query? Notion: I'm using **MySql 5.7** so the window function like **row_number()** is not supported and I can not upgrade the mysql to 8.0.
First I tried this:

```
var qry = DbContext.Set<CashFlowRecord>()
        .WHERE(t=>t.CreateTime <= '2023-12-31' && t.TotalAmount > 0)
        .GroupBy(t => t.MemberId)
        .Select(t=>new { MemId = t.Key, Latest = t.OrderByDescending(e=>e.CreateTime).First()});

var lst = (await qry.ToDictionaryAsync(t => t.MemId, t => t.Latest)).Select(t=>t.Value).ToList();
```

A **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException** exception thrown because MySql 5.7 has no Row_Number() function but the EF translate the `.OrderByDescending(t=> t.CreateTime).Take(1)`  to Row_Number().

The Error Message:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY `c0`.`MemberId` ORDER BY `c0`.`CreateTime` DESC) AS `row`**

**I dont konw how to fix this issue, I got no idea and I could not upgrade either one.**

---

updated: there seems no better solutions for this issue than using `FromSqlRaw`. So I suggest upgrading MySql and EF core at the same time.

Comment: `a quite simple SQL query` on the contrary, that's invalid SQL that only works due to MySQL quirks and can have serious performance issues from one minor 5.7 version to the next, precisely because it's a quirk. You can't have non-aggregate columns in `SELECT`. The `TotalAmount,CostAmount,BonusAmount` values you see are *essentially random* - if there are 100 rows in a single group, MySQL will pick an arbitrary one. There's no guarantee it will be the same one from one execution to the next either.

Comment: `EF Core 5 does not support projection after Groupby` that's incorrect. If it didn't, none of the `GroupBy` queries shown in all the docs would work. You're trying to use an invalid query though, one that can't be translated as is. `the EF translate the ... to Row_Number().` that's the only *real* way of executing the query you want without returning random data. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId ORDER BY SomeField)` will generate a row number for each row in a `MemberID` set, using an explicit order.

Comment: BTW you're using a combination of unsupported databases and libraries. MySQL 5.7 is out of support. EF Core 5 is also out of support. MySQL 8 is 7 years old already. If you can't upgrade to MySQL 8.0, you'll have to hand-code the quirky SQL query and map its results with `FromSqlRaw...`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I never use group by like this but the SQL query indeed works well in the old system in which the cashflow table contains over 100K records. I don't know whether it's a 5.7 version quirk. and using `FromSqlRaw` is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Maybe upgrading the MySql to 8.0 is the only practical solution I suggest.

Comment: `indeed works well` only because you didn't notice it's very slow, or that it returns unexpected results. 100K rows is *very little data*. `I don't know whether it's a 5.7 version quirk` yes it is, it's [mentioned in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). In fact, the docs say the behavior changed in 5.7.5 As for the performance degradation, you'll find SO questions asking why performance degraded by 70% from one 5.7 version to the next. The functional dependency check change would be enough to introduce delays in such a query